# How to redirect external links on my posts to a redirect page (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

(WordPress)

1. I want to redirect visitors that click on my external links to a page 
   like (you are leaving our site after x seconds )
   then they redirect to the external links
2. I want to put ads on this page to increase my page view and earn extra money
   can anyone helping me out.

Comment: You need javascript for that. PHP redirects immediately, without sending page content to the browser.

Comment: Javascript redirects are done with `window.location = "http://www.example.com";`. You would just need a timer to count down and then do that when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

On your pages you would include this code (I'm assuming you're using jQuery)

```
$('a .external').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "leave.html?q=" + encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Add the class 'external' to any external links

Then on the page `leave.html` put this in. Change 5000 to the number of milliseconds you want the user to be on the page.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1).slice(2));
}, 5000);
```

Comment: can u explain more to me i am new at this field

Comment: Yeah, no problem! :)